# Is USB host supported by hardware?

Tags: hardware, usb-on-the-go

Im using an Acer Liquid E2 Duo (with Androium 5, which is based on 4.4.2).

I would like to know how i can find out if OTG is supported on the hardware side, or if someone knows about this phone specifically.

Comment: Have you tried an USB checker app? Some are listed [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_storagemedia#group_534).

Comment: @Izzy i tried usb otg checker and that says my device is ready for otg

Comment: Then I'd assume it does. As you already have that device, why not simply try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first place to go, would probably be to the specifications' page on the manufacturer's website or other alternative reputable websites offering the same kind of information.

For a quick check [this website](https://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/39092813) doesn't state your device as being supported for USB OTG. The other one [GSmarena: Acer Liquid E2](https://www.gsmarena.com/acer_liquid_e2-5418.php), doesn't list this functionality, which most likely means your device doesn't support OTG.

The other ways of checking may be using an application e.g [USB OTG Checker ✔](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.faitaujapon.otg) , just as Izzy mentioned, they normally check the presence/absence of certain parameters required for USB OTG to work. For example they  check;

> the presence of USB Manager,  the presence of
>   `android.hardware.usb.host.xml` or find the list of connected OTG USB
>   devices.

It is important to note that this functionality should be supported by the **hardware** as well as **the kernel of the phone**.

<sup>Additionally some users claim the possibility of enabling USB OTG by using tools as  StickMount or USB OTG Helper (if the chipset supports OTG and the device doesn't) when rooted , or using a using a usb Y cable (if your chipset doesnt support OTG) to power up pendrive externally</sup>.